# how to install Glassfish Open source Edition 3.1, Glassfish V3?

Tags: java, glassfish

Glassfish Open source Edition 3.1,  Glassfish V3 , what is the difference ?

what is the difference in installation ?

thanks.

Comment: do you want to install it with netbeans or only gfs v3?

Answer (score 0):

Installing Glassfish v3 with NetBeans 6.9.x is super simple.

Here is the link for 6.9.1 with GFS v3

http://netbeans.org/downloads/6.9.1/

Answer (score 0):

You may download GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1 from the following location: 
http://glassfish.java.net/downloads/3.1-final.html

To get started, simply unzip the zip distribution. For more details, please refer to Quick Start Guide:
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/index.html